# Vue js issues with passing event and index as parameter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to display a list of images that users can change by clicking and uploading a new image. The first image is going to be a default add image. I am having issues sending both and index and an event to a method. If I display the index of the photo in the html, it is correct. But, if I send the index to the method as a parameter, it is always 0. In other words, my use of {{index}} produces the correct index, but my use of console.log(index) produces 0. Looking for some advice. Thanks!

**html:**

```
<v-layout v-bind="binding">
     <v-flex v-for="(image, index) in imageData">
       <v-card  style="margin:10%;">
         {{index}}
         <label for="imgload">
           <v-card-media :src="image" v-if="imageData.length > 0"></v-card-media>
         </label>
         <input hidden id="imgload" type="file" @change="previewImage($event, index)" accept="image/*">
       </v-card>
     </v-flex>
   </v-layout>
```

**method:**

```
previewImage: function(event, index) {
     this.toggle="false";
     var input = event.target;
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = (e) => {
           console.log(index);
           if (index == 0) {
             this.imageData.push(e.target.result);
           } else {
            this.imageData[index] = e.target.result;
           }
         }
         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
   },
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can pass index as a data attribute instead,

```
<input hidden id="imgload" type="file" @change="previewImage($event)" accept="image/*" :data-index="index">
```

and in your method, get the index using `event.target.dataset.index`

```
previewImage: function(event) {
    const index = event.target.dataset.index;
    //...

           console.log(index);
    //...
   }
```

Comment: Does anyone know why this workaround is needed? I had the same issue