# Vue.js Send an index with @input event

Tags: vue.js

Vue version : 3.1.1

Hey guys,

I'm working with dynamic Creation Component, which means a user can add whatever of component he wants.I create it base on this documentation [dynamic component creation](https://itnext.io/dynamic-component-creation-in-vue-js-b002bb41aaf4).

And I use this component [vue image uploader](https://github.com/kartoteket/vue-image-upload-resize).

I need to send an index when the user wants to upload the image, like this :

```
<div v-for="(line, index) in lines" v-bind:key="index">
{{index}}//if i log the index its 0,1,2,3 and its ok
...
          <image-uploader
            :preview="true"
            :class-name="['fileinput', { 'fileinput--loaded': line.hasImage }]"
            :capture="false"
            :debug="0"
            :auto-rotate="true"
            output-format="blob"
            accept="image/*"
            @input="setImage(output , index)"
            :ref="'fileUpload'+index"
          >
...
```

And the setImage funciton :

```
    setImage: function(output,index) {
      console.log(index);
      console.log(output);
      return ;
      this.lines[index].hasImage = true;
      this.lines[index].image = output;
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", output);
      Ax.post(upload_route, formData, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
      })
        .then(response => {
          // upload successful
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

And the log result is:
[image: console log]

The index always is 0 :(

How can i send an index when i want to upload it?

I read this [passing event and index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761985/vue-js-issues-with-passing-event-and-index-as-parameter) and test it but it's not working on component.
Because This is a custom event not a DOM event.

what should I do?

thanks.

Comment: @nmfzone Can you please take a look.

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Comment: But to send this index, you have to have an index, where is your index coming from? Got a v-for? If you don't create a computed property, or even a method that will dynamically issue that index, with each call it raises a value in the index so you have control.

Comment: Sorry, your mention seem not notifies me. Let me take a look @meti

Comment: It seems that `@input` takes function name, not return value of the function. Since you're calling `setImage(output, index)`, you're actually passing return value of `setImage` to the `@input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're actually passing the return value of `setImage` to the `@input`, not the method.

You can't just add extra parameters to `setImage`, as ImageUploader component just emit an `image` to the `setImage`. If you need to add extra parameters to that method, you need to create custom element that wrap ImageUploader.

It's something like this:

**ImageUpload.vue**

```js
<template>
  <image-uploader
    :debug="0"
    :autoRotate="true"
    outputFormat="blob"
    :preview="true"
    :className="['fileinput', { 'fileinput--loaded' : hasImage }]"
    :capture="false"
    accept="image/*"
    doNotResize="['gif', 'svg']"
    @input="setImage"
    v-on="listeners" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    index: {
      required: true,
      type: Number
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      hasImage: false,
      image: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    listeners() {
      const listeners = { ...this.$listeners };

      const customs = ["input"];

      customs.forEach(name => {
        if (listeners.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
          delete listeners[name];
        }
      });

      return listeners;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setImage(image) {
      this.hasImage = true;
      this.image = image;

      this.$emit("input", this.index, image); // here, we emit two params, as index for the first argument, and the image at the second argument
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Then, you can use that component something like this:

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="(line, index) in lines" :key="index">
      <image-upload :index="index" @input="setImage"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ImageUpload from "./ImageUpload";

export default {
  components: {
    ImageUpload
  },
  data() {
    return {
      lines: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setImage(index, image) {
      console.log("Result", index, image);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

See the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ccn0e

Comment: Is it working @meti? Atleast add a comment to confirm if it's working or not.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [$event](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers) like this...

`@input="setImage($event, index)"`

...and you're done!